# How to tell google that a specific page of my website disappeared and won't come back?

Tags: google-search-console, http-status-code-410

I have a website where 50% of the pages have a limited lifetime.

To give an idea, 4.000 pages appear each week and the same amount disappears.

By "appearing" and "disappearing", I mean that the appearing pages are completely new ones, and disappearing pages are removed from the website forever. There is no "this new page replaces this old page".

I naively used a 410 code on every URL where a page had disappeared.
Meaning the url http://mywebsite/this-page-was-present-until-yesterday.php returned until yesterday a `200 OK` code, and returns now a `410 Gone` code.

I didn't use no redirect, because I want to tell the user that the URL he accessed *isn't wrong*, but that *it is expired*.

**The problem is** : Google won't acknowledge this information. It is still crawling the pages and Webmaster Tools alerts me as if the page was 404 broken. This affects significantly my "reputation".

Did I do something wrong ? How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) of Google enables you to delete certain pages.
You can find this under "crawler access".

Try adding a noindex header.

Comment: With a noindex header the pages will never be shown in search results. It's a violent solution to the problem and I doubt that is the requested result.

Comment: My pages already have <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noodp" /> ; and I can't delete manually all the pages each week

Answer (score 0):

It's always a very good idea to make your own error page. This can save you a lot of visits through broken links.

[.htaccess error pages](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml)

Comment: The problem isn't the visits on the page (which is customized) but that google doesn't treat 410 code properly